# Android: How do I access an AsyncTask from a PendingIntent created by a status bar notification?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, status, android-notification-bar, android-pendingintent

My application starts an `AsyncTask` which downloads a file from a URL.  At the same time it creates a status bar `Notification` which tells the user the percentage complete of the download.

I'm trying to make my application respond to clicking the notification.
If the download is still in progress, I want to show a `DialogInterface` which asks them if they want to stop the download.  Clicking yes should stop the download.

The problem I'm having is I'm not sure how to access my Async task from the `PendingIntent` that I set up for the notification.  I can get the `DialogInterface` to show easy enough, but I'm not sure how to show the Activity that's going off where the download is to stop it.

I tried making a Helper class that had access to the notification as well as the File object referring to the downloadable file, but I get an error saying that the object is not serializable (it does implement `Serializable`).  The helper class also included a member that would hold the progress of the download which is what I would use for the condition on whether to show the dialog or not.

I was thinking of using a Brodcast Action and receiver, but I'm not sure where to put the receiver.  Would it go in the class that extends the `AsyncTask`?

Any help would be appreciated.
This is the `PendingIntent` attached to the `Notification`.  If you would like to see more code, just ask.

```
public class DownloadNotificationActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

    Intent i = getIntent();

    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int which ) {
            switch ( which ) {
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE :
                    // Yes button clicked
                    // Stop download
                    finish();
                    break;

                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE :
                    // No button clicked
                    finish();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    if ( /* download not complete */ ) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder( this );
        builder.setMessage( R.string.stop_download ).
                setPositiveButton( R.string.yes, dialogClickListener ).
                setNegativeButton( R.string.no, dialogClickListener ).show();
    }
    else {
        // Access file
    }

}
}
```

So to be clear, I have a `ViewDetailActivity` class.  It has an inner class called `DownloadFile` which extends `AsyncTask` and is executed when the user clicks a button on the screen.  In the `doInBackground()` method of `DownloadFile`, a download of an mp3 is started from a URL and a status bar `Notification` is created and updated based on the amount of the file that is downloaded.  The `PendingIntent` of the `Notification` is created with the `DownloadNotificationActivity` (code shown) and it should show a dialog which, of "Yes" is selected, should cancel the download in the `AsyncTask`.

My issue is that I need to get word back to the `DownloadFile` task that the download has been canceled and I'm not sure how to access the `DownloadFile` from the `DownloadNotificationActivity` in order to cancel it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In your `asynctask`, you need to check for `isCancelled()` in the `doInBackground()` and abort when cancelled. From your notification, you call `cancel()` on the `asynctask`.

To do this you need to pass reference to the `AsyncTask` to your notification activity.

For example:

You create the AsyncTask like this:

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) { //be sure to check isCancelled here, i.e. if (isCancelled()) break;
```

Then in your main `Activity` you create the `AsyncTask` like:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private MyAsyncTask zeTask;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              zeTask= new MyAsyncTask();
              zeTask.execute();
```

Then, when you create the notification and want to cancel the async task just refer to it as zeTask. The MyAsyncTask needs to be in the same activity as the notification and zeTask can be a variable that holds the reference to your AsyncTask.

```
switch ( which ) {
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE :
                    zeTask.cancel();
                    finish();
                    break;
```

Comment: That's the issue I'm having is actually passing reference of the `AsyncTask` to the activity above.  I tried to implement `Serializable` on the `AsyncTask` and use `putExtra()` on the `Intent` I set up as the `PendingIntent`, but I got an exception saying that the object is not serializable.  Is there another way to pass a reference to the AsyncTask to my activity?

Comment: Ok I think that the way I'm doing it just won't work.  The notification task I posted was ONLY for use as the `PendingIntent` when the status bar notification was clicked.  The `AsyncTask` was actually in the class that handled the screen where you can click to download the file.  Sounds like I need to move my `AsyncTask` to the `DownloadNotificationActivity` and execute it in the `onCreate` of that class.  Then handle the `onClick` event for the notification.  I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: Trying what I said in my previous comment did not work.  I thank you for your assistance @Motes.  I've updated the topic with more info (at the bottom).  I feel like I'm going about this the wrong way.  I need to look for other options.  I thought about trying a `Broadcast` and `BraodcastReceiver` but I'm not sure how well putting a receiver on an `AsyncTask` will work.